# LDAP subdepartments?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

Hi I am using c# and LDAP protocol. Is there anyway of finding sub-departments? In c#
E.g: Department: Finance, Sub dept: Procurement , Sub dept: Clerks

I am doing this in c#

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer you have to provide more detail. Im not sure what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this post should do the trick for you -> [How can I figure out my LDAP connection string?](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string)

Using the example from the link with the OU's provided in your question should get you following LDAP string

```
LDAP://dc1.corp.domain.com/OU=Clerks,OU=Procurement,OU=Finance,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Comment: I can get the LDAP string via a class i wrote but how do i get the OUs alone? slipt the string?